# Establish connection with websocket server using TCP

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, websocket

I'm trying to connect to websocket server using TCP.
But, I have problems doing it - empty response coming from server.
What I am doing.
First, I build the "handshake" header it looks like folows:

```
"GET /mqtt HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "Host: broker.mqttdashboard.com\r\n" +
    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" + "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" + "Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==\r\n" +
    "Origin: broker.mqttdashboard.com\r\n\r\n";
```

Next I create socket and sending header to the server:

```
var ips = Dns.GetHostEntry("broker.mqttdashboard.com");
        sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
        sock.Connect(ips.AddressList[0], 8000);
sock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header));
        var buf = new byte[4096];
        var rec = sock.Receive(buf);

        var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf, 0, rec);
```

"Handshake" is successful, since I am getting next headers in response:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake
upgrade: websocket
connection: upgrade
websocket-origin: broker.mqttdashboard.com
websocket-location: ws://broker.mqttdashboard.com/mqtt
```

And after that I cann't connect. I am building next connection headers:

```
"CONNECT clientId-nVqGddbrRK@broker.mqttdashboard.com:8000 HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "host: broker.mqttdashboard.com\r\n" +
            "\r\n";
```

And I have empty response. Could you please point me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried reading the protocol specification: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455